# How can I create a Slack command with a file attachment

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I would like to create a Slack command `/command do-something-with-that-file` with at the same time, the user uploading the file.

So far, my command is received but there is no files in the payload.
Is this possible?

I have also added `files:read` in the scope but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Slack command can only accept text as input. If you upload a file at the same time, it wouldn't be a part of the payload and will be ignored (although uploaded, and accessible through file browser).

Some alternatives you could try though:

1. Use [`files.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.list) method - Look for files uploaded within a few seconds of the moment when you receive the command. The method accepts `ts_from` and `ts_to` parameters for this purpose.
2. Use [`file_shared`](https://api.slack.com/events/file_shared) event - Subscribe to this event in your app configuration. This event fires every time a file is uploaded in a channel visible to your bot. You could ask the app user to use a certain format to provide with a file upload, and look for a pattern in the event submission.
3. Use [message shortcut](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/shortcuts/using#message_shortcuts) - Once a user uploads a file, you can ask them to use the context menu to fire a message shortcut associated with your app. This message shortcut contains a reference to the message ID, which can be used to fetch the uploaded file.